# What type of output parameter of result Oracle package procedures which return ref cursors via SQL server linked?

Tags: sql, oracle, linked-server

I want to get results from the oracle procedure which return cursor from sql linked server, so what type of output parameter must be used, thank you ?

```
DECLARE @InputPara NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @OutputPara ?????????

EXECUTE ('BEGIN ? := Package.MyFunction(?,?); END;', @InputPara, @OutputPara OUTPUT) AT linked
```

Comment: What is the datatype being returned by `Package.MyFunction(?,?)`?

Comment: what is datatype i must set for @OutputPara

Comment: See my answer below (in few minutes).

Comment: The way you have it set up `@InputPara` will be bound to the return value of the function, `@OutputPara` will be bound to the first parameter to `Package.MyFunction`, and NOTHING will be bound to the second parameter to `Package.MyFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all and since what you are invoking is a function that returns  value, I'm not sure you need an anonymous block (i.e. `BEGIN` / `END`) and you may simply invoke the function with the parameter receiving the value returned by the function (as you did) and add (if the language allows it) the clause `INTO`.

Secondly, the order of the parameters being passed (i.e. `@InputPara, @OutputPara`) must match the order of `?`, meaning that in your case the statement should be (I'm using your syntax, not the one I suggested):

```
EXECUTE ('BEGIN ? := Package.MyFunction(?,?); END;', 
         @OutputPara OUTPUT                        ,
         @InputPara_1                              ,
         @InputPara_2                               ) AT linked ;
```

[Note that your have two parameters being passed to the function (`(?,?)`).]

As for your question (type of `@OutputPara`) it should be the same type being returned by the function (which, from your question I cannot assess it).

Comment: The function return a Cursor, so what type of @OutputPara i need set ?

Comment: IN that case, you need to handle the return "object" as a cursor. It depends on the DBMS you are working and invoking the Oracle's function. Check the web how to handle returned cursors in the specific DBMS you are invoking the function from (not Oracle, but the DBMS you are invoking from).